# How to implement my generic LinkedList in my Stack/Queue class in Java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, stack, implementation

I have this project where I have to implement my LinkedList data structure in a stack and queue classes. All the classes including my LinkedList are of generic type `<E>`. The problem is that I am getting a bunch of overflow and nullpointerexceptions errors. Here is my logistic:

My Stack and Queue classes are supposed to implement the LinkedList class I previously wrote, which runs flawlessly (I thoroughly tested it). My LinkedList is at the same time implementing the LinkedListImplementation, which only contains the "blueprints" of the methods I am supposed to use. In addition, I would like to say that all these files -> LinkedListImplementation.java, LinkedList.java and Stack.java are inside a package called `package1`.

Here are the methods (without code, since I am 110% sure it runs flawlessly):

```
//LinkedListImplementation.java:
package package1;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class LinkedListImplementation<E> extends Iterable<E>{
    //...
    //All the methods to be used go here. See the methods in LinkedList.java
}//End LinkedListImplementation Implementation Class




//LinkedList.java:
package package1;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList<E> implements LinkedListImplementation<E>{
    int size;
    Node<E> head, tail;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    class Node<E>{
        E data;
        Node<E> next;

        //Default Node constructor
        Node(E obj){
            this.data = obj;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    //Logic for all the LinkedList methods below.

    //This method contains its code, as an example...
    public void addLast(E obj){
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(obj);
        if( isEmpty() ){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            size++;
        }else{
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            size++;
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(E obj){
        ...
    }

    public void insert(E obj, int location){
        ...
    }

    //... Other methods, such as removeFirst(), removeLast(), remove(int location)
    //... size(), get(int location), contains(E obj), locate(int location)
    //... clear(), isEmpty().
}//End LinkedList Class
```

As you can see, I could have used the LinkedList class in java, but I am not allowed to use any libraries from java.util that are constructed and have default behavior i.e. LinkedList, Stack and Queue. I am supposed to write the logistic and implementations myself simulating their behavior.

Now, I want to implement a Stack that is comprised of Nodes, implementing my LinkedList. Here is my attempt:

```
//Stack.java:
package package1;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Stack<E> extends LinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E>{
    LinkedList<E> list;

    Stack(){
        list = new LinkedList<E>();
        testStack();
    }

    //START declaration of Stack methods
    public void push(E obj){ list.addFirst(); }

    public E pop(){ return list.removeFirst() }

    public int size(){ return list.size(); }

    public boolean isEmpty(){ return list.isEmpty(); }

    public E peek(){ return list.get(size()); }

    public boolean contains(E obj){ return list.contains(obj); }

    public void makeEmpty(){ list.clear(); }

    public Iterator<E> iterator(){ return list.iterator(); } 
    //END declaration of Stack methods

    //My tests to see if the Stack works
    public void testStack{

        Stack<Integer> testStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        //Test push method
        for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
            stack.push(new Integer(i));
        }
    }//End testStack

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            new Stack();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//End Main method

}//End Stack Class
```

That's my code. I have not even try approaching the Queue class because once I get the Stack one up and running, it will be really easy to implement the Queue one.

Whenever I run my code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at data_structures.LinearList.<init>(LinkedList.java:24)
    at data_structures.Stack.<init>(Stack.java:9)
    at data_structures.Stack.testStack(Stack.java:25)
    at data_structures.Stack.<init>(Stack.java:11)
    at data_structures.Stack.testStack(Stack.java:25)
    at data_structures.Stack.<init>(Stack.java:11)
    at data_structures.Stack.testStack(Stack.java:25)
    ...//A lot more of the same line 11 and 25 errors...
```

I assume that the error happens because of the for loop I have inside the `testStack` method and some kind of class instantiating mistake I have in my code. First error (Line 24) refers to the `LinkedList` class constructor. Second Error (Line 9) refers to the `Stack` class constructor. Third error (Line 25) refers to the instantiation of the stack inside the `runTests()` method, which is the following line: `Stack<Integer> testStack = new Stack<Integer>();`. Fourth Error (Line 11) refers to the `testStack` call inside the `Stack()` class default constructor.

Could someone help me to get to the correct approach of achieving my goal? Which again is to get a Stack structure up and running with my LinkedList data structure.

Thanks a lot for your help and time in advance!

Cheers!

---

Edit1:

The push method was wrong (it was the pop method). The pop method was added as well. These are the correct ones (they are corrected above as well)

```
public void push(){ list.addFirst(obj); } 
public E pop(){ return list.removeFirst(); }
```

Comment: Java already includes a `Stack`, a `Queue` and a `LinkedList`... why are you writing your own?

Comment: It is basically my assignment to replicate the LinkedList, Stack and Queue behavior without using Java's predefined classes.

Comment: Your `Stack()` constructor is calling `testStack()` method, which itself is initializing a Stack in the statement: `Stack<Integer> testStack = new Stack<Integer>();` That becomes recursive and you run into a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: I tried another approach before but I could not really get it up and running. I created another class in a separate file called StackTester that imported package1. In its' default constructor it instantiated a new Stack() and also ran testStack inside. Do you think this would be a better approach?

Comment: I tried the approach I told you about and fixing it and now it doesn't give me any problems at all! How could I print all the contents of my Stack() instance? because when I do a `System.out.println(stack);` (in this case stack is the instance of Stack() of type `new Stack<Integer>()` ) it just shows `data_structures.Stack@6f5f6479` (address). Thanks!

Comment: data_structures.Stack@6f5f6479 is the result a Object.toString () to get whatever you want you need to override toString () on your Stack class

Comment: @vsnyc Could you please post your answer as an actual answer so I can mark it as the correct response? Thanks!

Comment: @CesarA I've added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had defined your `Stack` constructor like below:

```
Stack(){
    list = new LinkedList<E>();
    testStack();
}
```

And your `testStack()` method is like below, it's missing `()`

```
//My tests to see if the Stack works
public void testStack(){

    Stack<Integer> testStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    //Test push method
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        stack.push(new Integer(i));
    }
}//End
```

Your `Stack()` constructor is calling `testStack()` method, which itself is initializing a Stack in the statement: `Stack<Integer> testStack = new Stack<Integer>();` That becomes recursive and you run into a StackOverflowError